# How to bind or merge QPainterPaths?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, drawing

I'm trying to create brushed **`arch`** in my widget so that it occupies top part of it. I've managed to draw it, but having difficult with filling it.
Can you help me?

```
void Curve::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {

     QPainter painter(this);
     painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
     painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#4681c5"), 2.5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));  /// #4681c5    

     QPainterPath path;
     path.moveTo(width()/2 + 85.2, 71);
     path.cubicTo(width()/2 + 86.2, 71, width()/2 + 97, 102, width()/2 + 137, 102);

     QPainterPath path2;
     path2.moveTo(width()/2 - 85.2, 71);
     path2.cubicTo(width()/2 - 86.2, 71, width()/2 - 97, 102, width()/2 - 137, 102);

     QPainterPath path3;
     path3.arcMoveTo(width()/2 - 95, 18, 190, 190, 26);
     path3.arcTo(width()/2 - 95, 18, 190, 190, 26, 128);

     QPolygonF leftpoly;
     leftpoly << QPointF(0, 0) << QPointF(0, 102) << QPointF(width()/2 - 137, 102);

     QPolygonF rightpoly;
     rightpoly << QPointF(width()/2 + 137, 102) << QPointF(width(), 102) << QPointF(width(), 0) << QPointF(0, 0);

     QPainterPath arch;
     arch.connectPath(path2);
     arch.connectPath(path3);
     arch.connectPath(path);
     QPainterPath fill;
     fill.addPolygon(leftpoly);
     fill.connectPath(arch);
     fill.addPolygon(rightpoly);
     painter.fillPath(fill, QBrush(QColor("#f68448")));

     path.addPolygon(rightpoly);
     path2.addPolygon(leftpoly);
     path3.addPath(path);
     path3.addPath(path2);
     painter.drawPath(fill);
}
```

The result of the code above is as follows:

[image]

I would like to fill it properly.

P.S.
I've tried the method `simplified`, `connectPath` even `united` but all didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be more careful about the way in which subpaths are directed when you connect them to form larger paths.  In particular, look at the beginning and end points of `path`, `path2` and `path3` in your code and then look at the order in which you connect them.

In this case you should be able to correct things by [reversing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#toReversed) `path2` and `path3` when combining them to form `arch`...

```
QPainterPath arch;
arch.connectPath(path2.toReversed());
arch.connectPath(path3.toReversed());
arch.connectPath(path);
```

[image: Output with reversed paths]